# AngularJS Component to Watch and Display Notification when UiRouter Route Changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I have two components on my page: Navigation component and Form component. I want to notify the user if they navigate away from the page (via clicking on the Navigation component or pressing the browser 'back' button) if the form is dirty. I have already implemented the dirty checks, but I don't know how to implement the notification.

I am using Angular 1.6, Components, and UI-Router. I have tried several solutions such but the `$log` was not being triggered.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',     e => { $log.log(e); });
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart',     e => { $log.log(e); });
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', e => { $log.log(e); });
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', e => { $log.log(e); });
```

Once I am able to detect when the route has changed, how would I be able to prevent the route from changing so I can display my notification that their form is dirty?

Comment: What version of ui-router are you using?  If it's 1.0+ you can use the `uiCanExit` hook.  https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs/blob/fd30352892c8c3646ccb78c1a8f9a0dddc49230a/app/contacts/editContact.component.js#L36-L44

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for my app as well. I'm sure I'll refine it, but this is what I've done.

First, I created a service named trafficCop that looks like this:

```
(() => {    
    class trafficCop {
        constructor() {
            this.currentController = undefined
        }

        register(currentController) {
            if (currentController) {
                this.currentController=currentController
            } else {
                this.currentController = undefined
            }
        }   

        allowExit(promise) {
            if (angular.isObject(this.currentController)) {
                if (!this.currentController.allowExit()) {
                    return promise.reject()
                }
            }
            return true
        }   

    }
    angular.module('myApp').service("trafficCop", trafficCop)
})()
```

Then in all of my states, I added a resolve that looks something like this:

```
(() => {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .config(($stateProvider) => {
            $stateProvider.state('orders', {
                    url: "/orders",
                    component: "orderHistory",
                    role: "order history",
                    resolve: {
                        onEnter: (trafficCop,$q) => trafficCop.allowExit($q)
                    }
                })
        })
})()
```

Then in any component controller that I do not want to allow to be exited when dirty, I injected trafficCop into the constructor and stored it to this.trafficCop and added code something like this:

```
    $postLink() {
        this.trafficCop.register(this)
    }
    $onDestroy() {
        this.trafficCop.register()
    }
    allowExit() {
        // code to determine if the user can leave goes here.
        return false
    }
```

Comment: How would I stop the route change if I detect the form is dirty? The logic for detecting if the form is dirty is located within the component. What would be the best way for me to access this logic from the run block?

Comment: Sorry. I added some additional detail.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Curious, is there any way for me to listen and prevent the route change from within my component controller?

Comment: I revised my answer. I needed to implement this for my app. I am sure this could be accomplished a bit cleaner with the global hooks, because basically the key is the trafficCop service and setting the currentController when necessary.